# Drupal 6: db_fetch_object postgresql

Tags: postgresql, drupal, postgresql-8.4

I have a function like this:

```
function choose_data(){    
db_set_active('data');
$sql=db_query("SELECT * FROM A "); 
 $cd = array(NULL => t('-- Choose Data --'));
while($row=db_fetch_object($sql)){
    $cd[$row->id] = t($row->id.$row->desc.'-'.$row->data);
}
db_set_active('default');
return $p_rek;
}
```

And I have this script to show the form:

```
    $form['header']['data_op'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('Choose Data'),
    '#default_value' =>123,
    '#options' => choose_data(),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="cie-inline">',    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

If I execute that function, I have list of options from table A. But, when I change to table B, it was only show last one result only. And, I try to change to table C, there are all result like when I execute from table A.

So, what the possibilites why that happened? Table A, B, C, are on same schema.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is in this line:

```
$cd[$row->id] = t($row->id.$row->desc.'-'.$row->data);
```

Table B doesn't have coloumn: ID. Case closed :)